# Export multiple hidden columns for Kendo grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

Here is the code for exporting multiple hidden columns for Kendo grid,

```js
var exportFlag = false;
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport", function (e) {
if (!exportFlag) {
        e.sender.showColumn(0);
        e.preventDefault();
        exportFlag = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.sender.saveAsExcel();
       });
    } else {
        e.sender.hideColumn(0);
       exportFlag = false;
    }
});
```

In the above code there are given the `e.sender.showColumn(0);` and I need to export n<sup>th</sup> number of columns (Export to multiple hidden columns) like this: `e.sender.showColumn(n);`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of hidden columns. Iterate all columns and if index is in array show it.

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
                return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
            }

var hidencoll = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // your hidden cols indexes

for(i=0; i< grid.columns.length; i++)
            {
                if (isInArray(i,hidencoll))
                    grid.showColumn(i); // grid.hideColumn(i);               
            }
```

or if you want the first n columns:

```
  for(i=0; i< grid.columns.length; i++)
        {
           if (i <= n)
                 grid.showColumn(i); // grid.hideColumn(i);               
        }
```